# Basic listnode assignment

Tags: java

I'm in an Intro to Data Structures class that works in Java, and I'm having trouble with a problem that was assigned for the class. The problem is as follows:

Complete the following method according to the specification.

```
// Insert a new Listnode<E> containing d after the first n Listnodes in 
// chain. If n is less than 1 or bigger than the number of Listnodes in 
// chain, throw IndexOutOfBoundsException. 
// Precondition: chain has at least one node 
// 
// Examples: 
// chain: "A" n: 1 d: "B" chain: "A" -> "B" 
// chain: "A" -> "B" n: 1 d: "C" chain: "A" -> "C" -> "B" 
// chain: "A" n: 2 d: "B" IndexOutOfBoundsException 
public static <E> void insertAfter(Listnode<E> chain, int n, E d) {
```

I know the first thing I need to do is figure out how many nodes are in "chain," and in order to do that there's a for loop (or while loop?) and a temporary variable involved, but I can't figure out what to do after that? Can you help? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you at least try something. See if that works and then come back here!?

Comment: You do not need to find how many nodes are in the chain, the point of a linked list is to be dynamic(add and remove elements when needed). all you need is a pointer to the next element in the chain. if the pointer is NULL you have reached the end of the list.